# How to find 2 values in column B, which share same column A

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, let's say I have a table called eats, with columns animal and plant.

How would I write a query for an animal that eats plant1 and plant2?

The best I can seem to do is get back all instances of plant1 and plant2, but I can't figure out how to make it so it's the same animal for both.

```
SELECT animal
FROM eats e
WHERE e.plant = "plant1" AND e.plant = "plant2"
```

So if that returned

```
horse   plant 1
pig     plant 1
horse   plant 2
```

I only want horse for the query I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to do it

```
SELECT count(distinct e.plant) as cnt,animal FROM eats e
WHERE e.plant IN('plant1','plant2')
GROUP BY e.animal HAVING cnt = 2
```

For further query,you can do as below:

```
   SELECT e1.* FROM eats e1
   JOIN 
  (
    SELECT count(distinct e.plant) as cnt,animal FROM eats e
    WHERE e.plant IN('plant1','plant2')
    GROUP BY e.animal HAVING cnt = 2
) e2 ON e2.animal=e1.animal
```

Comment: I'd recommend `COUNT(DISTINCT e.plant)` just in case multiple rows have the same value.

Comment: @MatBailie you are right,I have updated it and thank you